# Convert Multiple pandas Column into json

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

My dataframe df is like:

```
col_1  col_2    col_3
A      Product  1
B      product  2
C      Offer    1
D      Product  1
```

What i want is to convert all this column to json with the condition that row of col_2 and col_1 should be key value pair. I have tried the following:

```
df['col_1_2'] = df.apply(lambda row: {row['col_2']:row['col_1']}, axis=1)
df['final_col']=df[['col_1_2','col_3']].to_dict('r')
```

My first row  of df['final_col'] is:

```
{'col_1_2': {'product': A}, 'value': 1.0},
```

But what i want is :

```
{'product': A, 'value': 1.0}
```

Comment: Try this link  https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html

Comment: `df.apply(lambda x: {x['col_2']:x['col_1'], 'value':x['col_3']}, axis=1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add missing key with value by `col_3`:

```
df['final_col'] = df.apply(lambda row: {row['col_2']:row['col_1'], 'value':row['col_3']},
                            axis=1)
print (df)
  col_1    col_2  col_3                     final_col
0     A  Product      1  {'Product': 'A', 'value': 1}
1     B  product      2  {'product': 'B', 'value': 2}
2     C    Offer      1    {'Offer': 'C', 'value': 1}
3     D  Product      1  {'Product': 'D', 'value': 1}
```

If need output in list:

```
L = [{b:a, 'value':c} for a,b,c in zip(df['col_1'], df['col_2'], df['col_3'])]
print (L)
[{'Product': 'A', 'value': 1}, 
 {'product': 'B', 'value': 2}, 
 {'Offer': 'C', 'value': 1}, 
 {'Product': 'D', 'value': 1}]
```

Or `json`:

```
import json
j = json.dumps([{b:a, 'value':c} for a,b,c in zip(df['col_1'], df['col_2'], df['col_3'])])
print (j)

[{"Product": "A", "value": 1}, 
 {"product": "B", "value": 2},
 {"Offer": "C", "value": 1}, 
 {"Product": "D", "value": 1}]
```